# Stuck on > prompt in terminal after bad bash command, Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: bash, terminal, ubuntu-10.10

After typing a bad command in terminal like below, the prompt does not exit. Tried Ctrl+c, Ctrl+z, Ctrl+q. Nothing helps to exit > prompt.

```
[root@172.17.148.40|eco9]# vi /etc/lru.cfg'
> 
> vi /etc/lru.cfg
> 
> 
>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash waits for you to terminate the quoted string with another single quote character. So you can either do <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and exit `vi` in a normal way, or use <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to cancel the command.

`">"` is the default value of the `$PS2` variable, a.k.a secondary prompt string.

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl+ \` will send a SIGQUIT signal. Try that if Ctrl+C (sends a SIGINT signal) does not work.

Answer (score 1):

How about <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>, or just <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (and then <kbd>:q</kbd> to exit `vi`).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> works for me. Anyway, try adding the closing single quote and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.